# Is Plain Latin a thing?

Tags: contemporary-latin

> Plain language is writing designed to ensure the reader understands as quickly, easily, and completely as possible.
> Robert Leon Cooper (1989). *Language Planning and Social Change*. Cambridge University Press.

Plain language is particularly developed in English (it is then called Plain English) and many resources exist, even [an American governmental site](https://www.plainlanguage.gov).

Is there anything similar in Latin?
Some of the advice on the English sites can be applied without modification to Latin (use common words, avoid long sentences, etc.), but I think there are specifics to Latin prose.
Therefore I was wondering if there was a composition manual that focuses on clear, understandable Latin rather than imitating some ancient author.

**Edit.** I was thinking understandable to someone who reads Latin fluently, but such a style would probably be useful to learners.

Comment: Perhaps a helpful clarification: By "understandable Latin," do you mean Latin that is easily understandable to a Latin-learner, or to someone who speaks and writes Latin proficiently?

Comment: That's a good question.
I was thinking more of someone who reads Latin fluently, but such a style would probably be useful to those who are learning

Comment: There were literally hundreds of books written between the 18th and 20th centuries on prose composition, I'm not sure we should be so confident to say that all materials recommend classical authors. And I don't see what this has to do with being a native speaker.

Comment: This is just a random idea on my part, but you might argue that in an era where literacy was extremely low that the latin _spoken_ by most people was equal to "plain latin".